# Cloud Messaging in Cloud Functions: admin.messagin(...).send is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

My function is triggered by a database event and uses Firebase Cloud Messaging to send a notification to a topic. My first function works fine, but the second one keeps throwing this error:

```
2018-02-20T21:16:49.878Z E receiveMessage: TypeError: admin.messaging(...).send is not a function
at exports.receiveMessage.functions.database.ref.onCreate (/user_code/index.js:55:27)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:59:27)
at next (native)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:53:36)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:695:26
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

here is the index.js file:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
// exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
exports.recceiveInvitation = /* the function that works */;

exports.receiveMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{chatId}/{time}').onCreate((event) => {
    const chatId = event.params.chatId;
    console.log('messages', chatId);
    var sender = event.data.val().name;
    var messageContent = event.data.val().message;
    if(messageContent.length >= 100){
        messageContent = messageContent.substring(0,97)+"...";
    }
    const payload = {
        data: {
            title: `New Message from ${sender}`,
            body: messageContent
        },
        topic: chatId
    };

    return admin.messaging().send(payload);
});
```

I ran npm install firebase-admin, but I did not help.

Comment: Log the value of `admin.messaging()` and update your question with the result.

Comment: How should I log it? I tried, : var mesaging = admin.mesaging();
 console.log("Messaging: ",messaging);   but it didn't even log, it just gave me the same error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

change this:

```
return admin.messaging().send(payload);
```

to this:

```
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topicname,payload);
```

to be able to send notifications to topics.

---

*You can do the above, or check the note below*

## Note:

You need to update the `firebase-admin` npm package, to be able to use `send()`:

[image]

```
npm install firebase-admin@latest
```

more info here:-

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/node
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages

Comment: .send should work for topics: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_a_topic

Comment: yes I saw that after answering. Oh it will still work also https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#legacy_send_operations

Comment: Wow. It actually worked with sendToTopic. I would still like to know why mine didn't work

Comment: maybe u are using an old version? It seems it was released yesterday I think

Comment: @Bas in the other function, are you using `send()`?

Comment: No I didn't use send()

Comment: ahh okay yes `send()` has been released new and replaces sendtotopic/sendtodevice in version FCM v1. Check this was written yesterday https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/02/firebase-cloud-messaging-v1-now.html

Answer (score 1):

```
let message = {notification: {title: "your title",body: "your message",},token:"token of user device"
      };

admin.messaging().send(message)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.