# admin.messaging(...).send is not a function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am using firebase-admin to send a push notification via Cloud Functions, but I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: admin.messaging(...).send is not a function
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite (/user_code/index.js:43:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:59:27)
    at next (native)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
    at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:53:36)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:700:26
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Any idea why it's not working? I am using firebase-admin version 5.9.1, so it is the latest version. It should include the **.send** function but it's still not working. I have uninstalled the plugin and re-installed it, but still, it did not work.

This is the code I am using:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: "xxx",
    clientEmail: 'xxx@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
    privateKey: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----<KEY>-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
  }),
  databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com"
});

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref("xxx").onWrite((event) => {
    console.log("notify");

    const registrationToken = "xxx";

    // See documentation on defining a message payload.
    var message = {
        notification: {
            title: "You have a new service request",
            body: "this is the main body"
        },
        data: {
            score: '850',
            time: '2:45'
        },
        token: registrationToken
    };

    return admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cloud Messaging in Cloud Functions: admin.messagin(...).send is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48894575/cloud-messaging-in-cloud-functions-admin-messagin-send-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @PeterHaddad thanks but I saw that post already. Seems like he needed to send to a topic. However, I am not sending to a topic, thus I need to use .send and not  .sendToTopic. Also I already have the latest plugin installed and it's still not working. Any idea why?

Comment: did you check the `note`, and updated the firebase admin npm package?

Comment: @PeterHaddad Yes I updated it. I'm using version 5.9.1 of the firebase-admin package. That's the latest version, correct? It's still not working. Thoughts?

Comment: Please update your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: @JenPerson I've updated the question with my code. Any thoughts?

Comment: I copied and successfully ran your code with 5.9.1.  Likely some problem with your configuration.  Does your `package.json` show `"firebase-admin": "^5.9.1"`?

Comment: @BobSnyder thanks! Turns out I ran the firebase-admin plugin update in my project folder but I needed to go into my functions folder and run the update there. Now the functions package.json is showing 5.9.1! Thank you!! Let me know if I can mark your answer as the solution

Answer (score 2):

It should be `sendToDevice` not `send`, maybe something like this :

```
var message = {
    notification: {
        title: "You have a new service request",
        body: "this is the main body"
    },
    data: {
        score: '850',
        time: '2:45'
    }
};

return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, message)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error sending message:", error);
    });
```