# Trying to subscribe to topic on Firebase Cloud Messaging gives Error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

When i try to subscribe to a topic i get the following error:

> .subscribeToTopic is not a function

```
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
      messaging
        .requestPermission()
        .then(() => {
          return messaging.getToken();
        })
        .then(token => {
          messaging
            .subscribeToTopic(token, 'allUsers')
            .then(response=> {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.log('Error subscribing to topic:', error);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
        });
```

If I remove that line of `.subscribeToTopic` and add a POST call via http it works using the following url:
**https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/TOKEN/rel/topics/TOPIC_NAME**

I took a look to this question and the docs
[Cloud Messaging in Cloud Functions: admin.messagin(...).send is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48894575/cloud-messaging-in-cloud-functions-admin-messagin-send-is-not-a-function)

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the method `send` not `sendToTopic`:

```
// The topic name can be optionally prefixed with "/topics/".
var topic = 'highScores';

var message = {
  data: {
    score: '850',
    time: '2:45'
  },
  topic: topic
};

// Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
admin.messaging().send(message)
  .then((response) => {
    // Response is a message ID string.
    console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error sending message:', error);
  });
```

> `send()` was released  and replaced `sendtotopic/sendtodevice` in version FCM v1
>
> https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/02/firebase-cloud-messaging-v1-now.html

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging

Comment: Hi Peter! thanks for answer. correct me if I'm wrong but that answer seems to be to send the message to the users already subscribed, but my issue is on how to subscribe them ```.subscribeToTopic(token, 'allUsers')``` lines gives me the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: To subscribe you need to use the admin sdk `// These registration tokens come from the client FCM SDKs.
var registrationTokens = [
  'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_1',
  // ...
  'YOUR_REGISTRATION_TOKEN_n'
];

// Subscribe the devices corresponding to the registration tokens to the
// topic.
admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(registrationTokens, topic)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log('Successfully subscribed to topic:', response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Error subscribing to topic:', error);
  });`

Comment: @devpato you need to install the package first `npm install firebase-admin --save` then you can import it `var admin = require('firebase-admin');` then initialize it `var app = admin.initializeApp();` check here then.https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics#subscribe-and-unsubscribe-using-the-adminSDK

Comment: The `firebase.messaging()` does not have the method `subscribeToTopic` https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging.html

Comment: i hae same issue , alr tried with `import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import { getMessaging, onMessage } from 'firebase/messaging'` still i cant to subscribe to topic .

Answer (score 2):

ah i solved it by handling on backend side ( nodeJS ) where the documentation is easy to handle topic.

so in this case we have alr **generate token on frontend side** **then in backend (nodeJS) we tried to subscribe to topic by the token.**

so in frontend end when we stream or `firebase.messaging().onMessage(payload => {` would like to trigger and show the message by topic.

FYI : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5289#issuecomment-899542765

so from the link we know that
**Notification.vue**

```
// these from frontend side ( for example vueJS )
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/messaging'
// firebase only for get token, onMessaging, request permission check, there is no function to subscribe topic by the token, so we handle on backend side my alternative
```

then in **server.js**

```
// these from backend side ( for examle nodeJS )
const { admin } = require('./firebase-config');
// admin.messaging().sendToTopic()
// admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic()
// admin.messaging().sendToDevice()
```

if you are looking for the **firebase-config.js** here is

```
/*
 * Initialize firebase
 */
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./firebase.json"); // you can get the .json file on firebase service account .

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://project-xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com"
});
module.exports.admin = admin
```

my implementation :

```
app.get('/firebase/notification', (req, res)=>{
  const registrationToken = req.body.registrationToken;

  admin.messaging().subscribeToTopic(registrationToken, 'myTopic')
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Successfully subscribed to topic:', response)

        const options =  notification_options;
        const message_notification = {
          notification: {
            title: 'Yogi Arif Widodo',
            body: '2 10 pm',
            url: 'https://localhost:8080',
            other: 'other data',
          }
        };
        admin.messaging().sendToTopic('myTopic', message_notification, options).then( response => {
```

so when i tested on firebase console send by topic `myTopic` my Notification.vue trigger these code

```
firebase.messaging().onMessage(payload => {
.....console.log
}
```